# When remove module in magento2 still issues showing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I removed the module in magento2 but it showed error after running the commands. can someone help me?

```
php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US
```

and flush the cache also. Still issues like

> Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class
>   Vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\Menutype does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: Are you disabling custom module? Any other module is dependent on this module?

Comment: no. I need to remove the category custom attributes also.

Comment: Can you please input more details?

Comment: I created a custom category attributes module for magento2 admin side. Now I don't need the module. I deleted the module folder and run the commands. but still issue is attribute does exist message is displaying

Comment: So if you have already data inserted into the attribute?

Comment: yes inserted into database